# Flask migrate couldn't read models?

Tags: python, heroku, flask-migrate

I am trying to get the "python manage.py db migrate" to work but I keep getting these two lines only.

INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.

INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.

Can someone explains what does the two lines mean? I am guessing the heroku backend that I am having couldn't compare the models.py and update the table. Correct me if I am wrong.

In my view.py, I have "from models import *" and 
in my app.py, I have "from view.py".

My friend has no problem migrating the database at all and he couldn't remember what he did to solve it.

I ran "python manage.py db show" and it shows me this

```
empty message

Revision ID: b8b188e67d59
Revises: 5b82870de25a
Create Date: 2018-08-31 13:24:27.359151
```

I ran this "select * from alembic_version;" and I get

### version_num

32a4b24d4961

Please let me know if the numbers makes any sense or the numbers are not helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Model that you are inheriting in the class. Is created with the help of same db which you are using.

Snippet :

```
Model = db.model

class TableName(Model):
    column_name1 = db.Column(String(20))
```

Comment: What will happen if I clear all the downgrade and upgrade?

Comment: If you clear all the contents of downgrade and upgrade then that file is of no use.